# How do I optimize the loading time of Google Earth Web Plugin if I have a very large KML file?

Tags: kml, google-earth-plugin

My client has a very large KML file, it contains around 6000+ placemarks and these placemarks have to appear as 3D models on the map. What's even worse is that the KML file does not contain that `<link>` tag for the COLLADA file, which means I have to traverse the KML file and attach a COLLADA file before it can be displayed on google earth. Now I can already traverse and add a 3D model for each placemark. I tested it with a very small KML file(which contains like less than 100 placemarks) and it worked great as expected...but when I used the very large KML file which had like 6000+ placemarks on it, the plugin just crashes and I am advised to refresh the browser, only to find it crashing again... :(

Any advice on this?
Is there a limit to the number of placemarks I can put on google earth web plugin?
How do I make the loading faster?

```
function render3DPoles(polesKmlLink){

                google.earth.fetchKml(ge,polesKmlLink, function(object){
            if(object){
                var item = object.getFeatures().getChildNodes().item(0);
                    var folder = item.getFeatures().getChildNodes();

                var latitude;
                var longitude;

                      for(var i = 0; i<folder.getLength(); i++){

                    var placemark = folder.item(i);

                    latitude = placemark.getGeometry().getLatitude();
                    longitude = placemark.getGeometry().getLongitude();

                        var model = ge.createModel('');
                    var location = ge.createLocation('');

                    model.setLocation(location);
                    var link = ge.createLink('');


                    link.setHref('insert URL of collada file here');
                    model.setLink(link);

                        location.setLatitude(latitude);
                        location.setLongitude(longitude);
                        model.setLocation(location); 
                        placemark.setGeometry(model);

                     ge.getFeatures().appendChild(placemark);
                     }

                     var la = ge.createLookAt('');
                     la.set(latitude,longitude, 25, ge.ALTITUDE_RELATIVE_TO_GROUND,180, 60, 100);
                     ge.getView().setAbstractView(la);

                } else {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                      alert('Bad or null KML.');
                      },0);
                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have dealt with dealing 10,000s of placemarks and other kml objects in the earth plugin and the best way I find is manage the data in a javascript object. dealing with them in standard kml would often crash things.

parse the kml before hand into something that you can handle as an object

start with:

```
var myModels = {};
```

for adding the first item if the id is 'foo' or a numeric do something like:

```
myModels['foo'] = { 
     description: 'some description for foo', 
     longitude: 100.12345,
     latitude: 45.4567
     linkUrl: 'http://mydomain.com/mymodels/foo.dae', 
     kmlObject: null};
```

now looking at the code from:

http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?exp=earth#creating_3d_models

you will have something similar to:

```
var placemark = ge.createPlacemark('');
  placemark.setName('model');
  var model = ge.createModel('');
.......
placemark.setGeometry(model);
```

now go:

```
myModals['foo'].kmlObject = placemark;
```

this will give you a quick reference to the model if you need to change it or remove it with just

```
myModels['foo'].kmlObject
```

no need to traverse the tree again.

one thing I found to be faster was to define kml client side and use parseKml to load it rather then create individual objects and add them.

also you can build in logic to only add the dae model that are within the area the user is looking at

to loop through all the items

```
var i, iModel;

for (i in myModels){
   iModel = myModels[i];

   if(myModels[m].kmlObject == null){  
       'add if statement to check if the models long/lats are in current view with
        ' iModel.longitude,  iModel.latitude
   } 
}
```

also rather than add everything in one operation, add 10-20 model in a single batch and use setTimeout to start another batch operation a second later and leverage  .executeBatch

https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/reference/google_earth_namespace#ab26414915202d39cad12bcd5bd99e739

Comment: After fetching, that's when I started adding the model.. I have updated the code above, so that you can see my code.

Comment: I'll see if I can use .executeBatch

Answer (score 0):

While there's no technical limit, the more you add the more resources get used.  Depending on the complexity of your models and other data, you will be able to add more or less, but 6000 is quite a lot of to display at once even for simple markers.

One solution for a large/complex KML is to create regionated KMLs instead, such that you are loading just the data you need at any given time, based on visible regions (see http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/regions.html )

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to see if I can do this.